# Creating Query Variable in TFS

Tags: tfs

We've a requirement to pass a custom query variable to filter the TFS records by running saved TFS query.

As we have @Me, @Project, @Today and [Any] can we use a custom variable like below, if yes how can we do this or is there any better approach for this.

`UserEmailAddress = @EmailAddress`, to get the records which matches the @EmailAddress which is passed from C# source code and we will add the variable and call the saved TFS query.

```
var variables = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "project", "ESE_Proj" },  {"EmailAddress",  "test} };

wiQuery = new Query(wiStore(), query.QueryText, variables);

wiTrees = wiQuery.RunLinkQuery();
```

Field name of a Work Item Type, we have created work item types, say example Person is a work item type with UserEmailAddress as field in it. I want to create a query in tfs such that user can call query from c# by passing email address by taking it from text box and run the query for the entered email address –

Comment: Is `UserEmailAddress` a custom field in these work items?

Comment: UserEmailAddress is a field name in TFS

And/Or                Field                     Operator                    Value
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                           Team Project          =                          Project
And                     Work Item Type      =                          Person
And                     UserEmailAddress  =                          EmailAddress

I want to add the Value ad EmailAddress and pass the value from C# and run this query from C#

Comment: A field name in a work item? And is it a built-in field, or is it a custom field?

Comment: Field name of a Work Item Type, we have created work item types, say example Person is a work item type with UserEmailAddress as field in it.

I want to create a query in tfs such that user can call query from c# by passing email address by taking it from text box and run the query for the entered email address

Comment: Thanks. You should update your question with this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to store the query in TFS. While you can create and use custom variables in c# with the API TFS has no understanding of them.

You can only use @me, @project, @today, and @currentiteration in a stored query.

Comment: I also use the API to run shared queries, but for some reason, it does not accept the @project variable. Any ideas why this is so?

Comment: You can't use @project in the do as It is not automatic. It's a Team Explorer feature. You need to pass all the "@xxx" into the query.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it. Because the query is also used by the rest of the team in the team explorer. I left the @project in there, but when I need it, I replace @project with the actual project name.